# Complex Tallies / Aggregation dc.js

Tags: d3.js, dc.js, crossfilter

I'm working on a dashboard to help companies analyze their cost across many dimensions.

I have it *mostly* working up at: https://jsfiddle.net/gkke38wk/4/

There are a few things I cannot seem to get working.

**SHOW COUNT OF UNIQUE PO BY CONTRACTOR:**

I have been able to show this accurately on the Data-Table as you can see in the fiddle, but for some reason nothing I try on the rowChart will show anything but total PO's rows, not Unique PO (This is flattened data, and each line item is a row in the datatable, so one PO may have many rows. *FOR EXAMPLE*, Bill has only submitted one PO, but it has two lines. The chart shows (2) for Bill).

```
  contractorChart
        .dimension(contractors)
        .group(contractorGroup)

  contractorChart
        .dimension(uniqueDim)
        .group(contractorGroup)
```

**SHOW TOTAL AMOUNT OF PO**

On the Data Table which is mostly working, I want the total column to show the aggregated total of all rows for that PO, not just the first match. In my `uniqueDim` function, it only works by aggregating unique PO numbers, not the entire PO object. I'm not sure how to aggregate the total.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In rowCharts, the displayed keys and values are determined solely by the group. The dimension is used only for filtering, so switching out the dimension shouldn't result in any change in the displayed values. You'll need to have your group track unique POs rather than the dimension. This is a bit hard to do correctly and efficiently, but I'd recommend using [Reductio exception aggregation](https://github.com/crossfilter/reductio#exception-aggregation), in which case it is just a matter of defining a Reductio reducer and a value accessor on your chart:

```
  reductio()
    .exception(function(d) { return d.po; })
    .exceptionCount(true)(contractorGroup)      

  contractorChart
        .width(800)
        .height(200)
        .margins({ top: 20, left: 10, right: 10, bottom: 20 })
        .dimension(contractors)
        .group(contractorGroup)
        .ordinalColors(['#3182bd', '#6baed6', '#9ecae1', '#c6dbef', '#dadaeb'])
        .valueAccessor(function(d) { return d.value.exceptionCount; })
        .label(function (d) {
            return d.key;
        })
        .title(function (d) {
            return d.value;
        })
        .elasticX(true)
        .xAxis().ticks(4);
```

As far as the data table, you have the right idea of creating a "fake dimension" as suggested in the dc.js FAQ, but you actually want a fake dimension with an aggregated value. So base it on a group instead:

```
var uniqueDim = {
    bottom: function (num) {
      var pos = poDimension.top(Infinity);
      // Uses top because the version of Crossfilter being used
      // doesn't support group.bottom.
      return poGroup.top(num)
        .filter(function(d) { return d.value > 0; })
        .map(function(d) {
            var currPo = pos.filter(function(g) { return g.po === d.key; })[0];
          return {
            po: d.key,
            total: d.value,
            contractor: currPo.contractor,
            complexity: currPo.complexity
          };
      });
    }
  };
```

Working example of both: https://jsfiddle.net/33228p1d/2/

Comment: Note - filtering on the fake dimension is broken. Looking at it now :-)

Comment: Issue was that group.top returns groups with 0-values for which no corresponding records exist in poDimension. Need to filter the groups to those with positive values for use in fake dimension.

Comment: Works great! Why are we using 'exceptionCount' to replace value?

Comment: Cool :-) Using that property just because Reductio uses objects as values so that it can track multiple measures per group. The property it uses for the unique count measure is `exceptionCount`.

Answer (score -2):

Try the following code:

```
contractorChart
    .width(800)
    .height(200)
    .margins({ top: 20, left: 10, right: 10, bottom: 20 })
    .dimension(contractors)
    .group(contractorGroup)
    .ordinalColors(['#3182bd', '#6baed6', '#9ecae1', '#c6dbef', '#dadaeb'])
    .label(function (d) {
        return d.key;
    })
    .title(function (d) {
        return d.value;
    })
    .elasticX(true)
    .xAxis().ticks(4);
```

A minor addition such as:

```
contractorChart
    .width(800)
    .height(200)
    .margins({ top: 20, left: 10, right: 10, bottom: 20 })
    .dimension(contractors)
    .group(contractorGroup)
    .ordinalColors(['#3182bd', '#6baed6', '#9ecae1', '#c6dbef', '#dadaeb'])
    .label(function (d) {
        return d.key;
    })
    .title(function (d) {
        return d.value.exceptionCount;
    })
    .elasticX(true)
    .xAxis().ticks(4);
```

Comment: It would be nice if you could add more explanation to your code. How does it solve the problem?